# Access error while reading excel sheet from S3 using python xlrd module

Tags: python, excel, amazon-s3, urllib, xlrd

I am using below code to read an excel file from `Amazon S3` using `python` `xlrd` and `urllib` module but I am getting `Forbidden` access error. I know it's because I am not passing `AWS Access Key` and `AWS Secret Access Key`. I looked around to find a way to pass the keys as a parameter with `urllib` but couldn't find an example.

```
import urllib.request
import xlrd

url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket1/final.xlsx'
filecontent = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=filecontent)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
```

How can I read the excel from S3 using python xlrd module?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using boto API

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
import sys
import pandas as pd

    try:
           conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id = your_access_key, aws_secret_access_key = your_secret_key)
           bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_bucket')
           print ("connected to AWS/s3")
    except Exception as e:
           print ("unable to connect to s3 - please check credentials")
           print(e)
           sys.exit(1)

destFileName = "/tmp/myFile.xlsx"
k = Key(bucket, "path_to_file_on_s3/sourceFile.xlsx")
k.get_contents_to_filename(destFileName)

df = pd.read_excel(destFileName, sheet_name=Sheet1)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boto3 :

```
import xlrd
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket)
s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=filename)
body = s3_object['Body'].read()
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=body, on_demand=True)
```